# Replace null values in spark dataframe with nested schema involving complex data types

Tags: apache-spark

I am building dataframe from json file and the schema keeps changing. Here is a sample of how schema looks like.

```
root
|-- id: string (nullable = true)
|-- emprecords: array (nullable = true)
|   |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|       |-- emprec: array (nullable = true)
|           |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|               |-- firstName: string (nullable = true)
|               |-- lastName: string (nullable = true)
|               |-- email: string (nullable = true)
|               |-- salary: integer (nullable = true)
```

Sample dataframe:

```
 ID     emprecords
 201    [[[Bruce, William,….
 202    Null
 203    [[[Mickey,Arthur……..
 204    Null
```

Nulls present in the rows associated with IDs 202 and 204 have to be replaced with empty array. The reason behind doing this is to use arrays_zip function to zip emprecords array with another array and arrays_zip function will populate null if either of the array columns invovled in zip operation is a null.

I have tried array_contains, transform functions to capture and replace null but no luck.

Comment: can you add some sample data ?? & expected output ??

Comment: What do you expect as output?

Comment: I have placed input dataframe in the description. In output dataframe null should be replaced with empty array i.e. [].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schema in the source dataframe will change. So, I can't use any column names explicitly while writing the UDF. So, here is the way to accomplish this:

val colName = "Array column name" i.e. emprecords in this case
val colIndex = df.columns.indexOf(colName) //where df is the dataframe created from json
val arrSchema = df.schema(colIndex).dataType //Reading the schema of dataframe's array column

val emptyArrUDF = udf(() => Seq.empty[Any],arrSchema) //UDF to create empty array

val df_updated = df.withColumn(colName,when(col(colName).isNull,emptyArrUDF()).otherwise(col(colName)))

Comment: You should mention this very required point of dynamic schema for a complex column in the question itself so that answerers think that way. Anyways its good that you solved it

Answer (score 0):

Filter null values in `emprecords` column & add `array()` if this column has null values else keep original data as it is.

**Updated**

```
scala> df.show(false)
+------------------------------------------+---+
|emprecords                                |id |
+------------------------------------------+---+
|[[[[some email, Srinivas, Reddy, 10000]]]]|100|
|null                                      |101|
+------------------------------------------+---+
```

Define empty json

```
scala> val emptyJson = """{"emprecords":[{"emprec":[{"firstName":"N/A","lastName":"N/A","email":"N/A","salary":0}]}]}"""
```

Get the `emprecords` column schema from current dataframe.

```
scala> val schema = df.select("emprecords").schema
```

use `from_json` to parse empty record with the schema.

```
scala> df
.withColumn("emprecords",
      when($"emprecords".isNull,from_json(lit(emptyJson),schema)("emprecords"))
     .otherwise($"emprecords")
)
.show(false)
+------------------------------------------+---+
|emprecords                                |id |
+------------------------------------------+---+
|[[[[some email, Srinivas, Reddy, 10000]]]]|100|
|[[[[N/A, N/A, N/A, 0]]]]                  |101|
+------------------------------------------+---+
```

Comment: This will not work because we have nested schema with various complex datatypes. The suggested solution will work for arrays of single data type.

Comment: Check now, Simple way is to define empty json record(replace defailt value for each properties of json), instead of  ```empty array```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is helpful -

### Load the test data

```scala
val df = spark.sql(
      """
        | select id, emprecords
        |  from values
        | (201, array(named_struct('emprec', array(named_struct('firstName' , 'tom', 'lastName', 'hank'))))),
        | (202, null)
        | T(id, emprecords)
      """.stripMargin)
    df.printSchema()
    df.show(false)

    /**
      * root
      * |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
      * |-- emprecords: array (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
      * |    |    |-- emprec: array (nullable = false)
      * |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
      * |    |    |    |    |-- firstName: string (nullable = false)
      * |    |    |    |    |-- lastName: string (nullable = false)
      *
      * +---+-----------------+
      * |id |emprecords       |
      * +---+-----------------+
      * |201|[[[[tom, hank]]]]|
      * |202|null             |
      * +---+-----------------+
      */
```

### Replace null

```scala
    df.withColumn("emprecords",
      expr("ifnull(emprecords, array(named_struct('emprec', array(named_struct('firstName' , null, 'lastName', null)))))"))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +---+-----------------+
      * |id |emprecords       |
      * +---+-----------------+
      * |201|[[[[tom, hank]]]]|
      * |202|[[[[,]]]]        |
      * +---+-----------------+
      */
```